# Манифест в проект С++(VIsual Studio)

Tags: c++

Как добавить файл манифеста в проект, но при этом так, чтобы в директории, где находится `exe` не обязательно должен быть `exe.manifest`. Просто во всех статьях только такой способ видел, и при этом эти файлы должны быть в одной директории. Либо нужен какой-то другой способ?

Comment: Манифест обычно добавляется как ресурс с идентификатором 1.

Comment: @VTT В xml вообще никто. Столкнулся с ним только сегодня из-за манифеста. Добавляется в `exe`-файл или как это работает?